Why windows Minifilter driver could not be stopped by sc or net command?
This is my first time to develop the minifilter drvier.
And i follow the document to create the inf file and use the
sc/net start command to start my minifilter driver success.
Unfortunately , when i want to stop my minifilter driver , the serivce status show NOT_STOPPABLE.

Therefore , i could not install the new testing minifilter driver and need to sc delete the service and restart the computer.
I also try the fltmc to load and unload the driver. When i use fltmc to unload the driver , the service still running and NOT_STOPPABLE. So i still need to sc delete the service and restart the computer.
I notice the PnpLockdown = 1 from the sample INF file. Does it means the pnp driver could not be stopped by sc or net ? If yes , how can i dynmaically load and unload the minifilter driver without restart the computer ?

Update1: Even i remove the "PnpLockdown=1" the service still can not be stopped.
If i remove the "PnpLockdown=1" , the driver service whill show
STOPPABLE. And if i try to sc stop service , the service will change
to NOT_STOPPABLE ...

==========================================================

Update2:
I solved the problem if i remove the wdfDriverCreate in DriverEntry
function. But i don't know why?
Because i found the microsoft minifilter samples don't have any  WdfDriverCreate , WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT , WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT
functions in the samples.
It is my tracking hisotry :
I use KMDF template sample from visual studio which alread create
the sample WDF driver&device for me. And then i add the
FltRegisterFilter,FltStartFiltering,FltUnregisterFilter to the right
place , and also revise the inf file to support minifilter.
Everything is work , but only "sc stop driver_service" failed.  Then i
check the minifilter driver microsoft sample from github and found
that there isn't any WDF function in DriverEntry.

   /*  ===> Here comment the related WDF Drvier template code

      WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT(&attributes);
      attributes.EvtCleanupCallback = MyEvtDriverContextCleanup;

      WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config,MyEvtDeviceAdd);

      status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject,
                               RegistryPath,
                               &attributes,
                               &config,
                              WDF_NO_HANDLE);

     if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
           TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, TRACE_DRIVER, 
           "WdfDriverCreate failed %!STATUS!", status);
           WPP_CLEANUP(DriverObject);
           return status;
     } 
    */

Thansk!

What does the registration code look like? You need to implement FilterUnloadCallback.

Yes , I have already implement FilterUnloadCallback. But this funciton need to be trigger by net stop or fltmc unload.      I test the command "fltmc unload" it will trigger the FilterUnloadCallback, but it didn't solve my probolem.  When i already unload the filter driver , then install new one  i need to restart computer ...  Because there is the running driver service ... so system could not reload the new driver .

Do you also have a DriverUnload? Help us help you by showing the code you are using, specifically DriverLoad (including filter registration), DriverUnload, and FilterUnloadCallback.

Hi @Luke thanks your feedback .  So I checked the DriverEntry again. The result is in Update 2 section.

Ah, I'm not very familiar with WDF as I write drivers without using any frameworks. I don't know enough about WDF to comment on it.
